# Keyboard accessible drop down menu not iterating through sub menu

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I need some help trying to solve the problem with my navigation. I can get the navigation to show the dropdown menu when a list item comes into focus using the tab button, but I can't get the tab to iterate through the dropdown (sub-menu), it just tabs to the next list item tag.

I have tried jQuery with no luck, now I'm just trying to use html, css and tabindex but still  no luck.

HTML

```
    <nav aria-label="Main menu" id="globalNav" >
      <ul>
       <li class="dropdown" tabindex="0" ><a href="#"><span itemprop="name">Welcome</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Visitor</a></li>
         <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Aid</a></li>
         <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     <li class="dropdown" tabindex="0"><a href="#"><span itemprop="name">Sports</span></a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Basketball</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Football</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Soccer</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
    #globalNav {
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(74, 61, 48, 0.3);
     padding: 0.54rem 0;
     margin-top: 30px;
     z-index: 10;
   }
   #globalNav ul {    
     list-style: none;
     display: table;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-size: 1rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   #globalNav ul li.dropdown {
     display: table-cell;
     padding: 0 10px;
     border-left: 1px solid #EEE;
     text-align: center;
   }

  #globalNav ul li.dropdown a{
    color: #4A3D30;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
   }
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown a:hover,
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown a:focus,
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown a:active{
       color:#666;
    }

    #globalNav ul li.dropdown a.active:after{
      width: 100%;
      background: #990000;
    }

    #globalNav ul li.dropdown a:after{
      content: "";
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      height: 2px;
      width: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
   }
  /*Children GlobalNav*/
   #globalNav ul li.dropdown a ul.sub-menu {
   }

    #globalNav ul li.dropdown  ul.sub-menu {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      z-index: 100;
      text-transform: none;
      min-width: 256px;
      max-width: 256px;
   }

    #globalNav ul li.dropdown:hover  ul.sub-menu,
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown:focus ul.sub-menu,
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown:active ul.sub-menu{
     display: block;
     background-color: #dcd8d6;
     color: #4a3d30;
   }
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown ul.sub-menu:hover,
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown ul.sub-menu:focus,
    #globalNav ul li.dropdown ul.sub-menu:active {
      background-color: #3f79c1;
    }

   #globalNav ul li.dropdown ul.sub-menu li a {
    padding: 8px;
   }
```

Here is my codepen
http://codepen.io/nicban/pen/vmEEPr

I feel like I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use some script to add a class to the item that has focus and walk up the DOM to add it to ancestors so that I can display them. I also remove the class when the focus changes.

It has been a while since I have reviewed it to remove / tweak any dumb bits.

Part of the issue you are having is that you are using `display: none`, which means a keyboard will never find it. If you use an off-screen technique, then the user can tab into the control.

Also, please remove `role="menuitem"` throughout as well as `tabindex="0"`. The former implies interaction you are not supporting (such as the arrow keys) and the latter creates extra tab stops that do not announce themselves correctly to screen readers.

```
    // Get the nav by id
    var pNav = document.getElementById("globalNav");

    function unClassy(){
      try {
        // Remove the focus class
        pNav.classList.remove("focus");
        // Remove the focus class from all its descendents
        pNavDesc = pNav.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for( var i = 0; i<pNavDesc.length; i++){
          pNavDesc[i].removeAttribute("class");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      } 
    }

    /* For any clicks, clear the focus class from the nav and all its descendants, essentially closing the menu when a user clicks/taps outside of it. */
    document.documentElement.onclick=function() {
      try {
        unClassy();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

    /* Manipulate focus classes in navigation. */
    function classy(){
      try {
        unClassy();
        // Add the focus class to items that have focus
        // Get the element that currently has focus
        var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
        // If that element is the primary nav, add the class
        if (focusedElement.id == pNav.id){
          // Add the focus class
          pNav.classList.add("focus");
        }
        // If nav contains the focused element, add the class
        if (pNav.contains(focusedElement)){
          focusedElement.classList.add("focus");
          el = focusedElement;
          while (el.parentNode) {
            el.classList.add("focus");
            el = el.parentNode;
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

    /* Delay the assigning of classes to give the :focus a chance to catch up. There has to be a better way for this. */
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("keydown", delayClassy, false);
    function delayClassy(){
      try {
        setTimeout(classy, 200);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Great . Your example worked for me. Thank you so much!